# ptrace-scope is unaccessible

Tags: kernel, 14.04

When installing Ubuntu 14.04 the following message came up when some component install seemed to go awry:

```
if install fails set /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace-scope to 0
```

I have tried editing the file in question by means of:

```
sudo gedit /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace-scope
```

Then copy the file to `/home/myname/Documents`, edit it, which works fine there. And then try to `mv` it back, without luck. Each time it comes up that the file does not exist.

No doubt there is a simple solution for this, and any help in getting around whatever is blocking this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, this works:

`echo "0" | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope > /dev/null`

You should be able to see the content of the file with:

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`.

It should be either `1` or `0` .